# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate query method not retrun right number of records

Tags: sql, jdbc, rds

We use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to query data from database. Running query manually, I can see there are 21 records. However, when our system run below query, it returned 20 records, while in some cases, it does return the right number.

```
final MapSqlParameterSource sqlParam = new MapSqlParameterSource();
sqlParam.addValue("col_name_1", param1)
    .addValue("col_name_2", param2)

final List<ObjectA> productGroups = this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(
    SQL_QUERY,
    sqlParam,
    (rs, rowNum) -> {
        final int col_A = rs.getInt("col_name_3");
        final String col_B = rs.getString("col_name_4");
        return new ObjectA(col_A, col_B);
});
```

I wonder how this happened? How should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you maybe looking at uncommitted data in your other session? Or maybe using a different database?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah I also thought it's caused by some inconsistency. But after checking, the last updated time for that missing row was two years back. It's wired that sometime it do return the right number.